# Tetra Master: What are the full rules?

Tags: final-fantasy-9

Can somebody explain to me the full set of rules for tetra master?

I get that you place the cards in turn, and the arrows correspond to the direction of attack.

I don't understand the X/P/H you see on the cards.

Any info would help me understand, as I just keep losing my cards :(

Comment: Here is a useful and visual guide: http://www.ffexodus.com/ff9/side18.php

Answer (score 8):

Simply put the numbers and letters on a card represent the attack value, attack type, and defensive values (physical and magical) of that card.

For example:

**1P24**

**1** (Attack value) **P** (Type - Physical) **2** (Physical defence) **4** (Magical defense)

The card's type decides which defensive value it attacks when placed. In the above example, Physical cards attack the physical defence of adjacent cards.

M - Magic cards - attack the magical defense

X - Power cards - attack the lowest of the two values.

Cards with A as a stat have a special behaviour.

I refer you to this [FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197338-final-fantasy-ix/faqs/9671) found at GameFAQS for a more in depth explanation.